# UNION ALL Statement Failing

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to UNION ALL around 20 or so tables to consolidate into a single view. I keep getting an error that states:

> 'The numeric value XXXXX is not recognized'.

This error is contained in 1 column in each of the tables, but the data type for that column is `VARCHAR(256)` in each of the tables. No matter what I cast the column to I still get the same error.

The `UNION ALL` works perfectly if I comment that column out.

I've tried casting all columns to the same datatype, no luck.

I've tried commenting out the column in question, which works, but I need that column.

I've tried only UNION-ing a few of the tables, which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, depending on the document type.

```sql
    SELECT
    CAST(QUICKBOOKS_MEXICO.BILL_LINE.DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(256)) AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM QUICKBOOKS_MEXICO.BILL_LINE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    CAST(QUICKBOOKS_EUROPE_BV.PURCHASE_LINE.DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(256)) AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM QUICKBOOKS_EUROPE_BV.PURCHASE_LINE
```

The columns should seamlessly UNION.

Here is the error message:

> Numeric value 'Exchange Gain Or Loss' is not recognized

It's worth mentioning that if I remove all the other fields BESIDES the column that is throwing the error from the query, it performs just fine.  Truly baffling!

Comment: If the `_BV` implies that you are using a view, then the problem may lie there.

Comment: It doesn't, `_BV` refers to a company in the Netherlands

Comment: Have you confirmed that each of those tables in the UNION ALL have the correct data type by querying the information schema?  It sounds like you have a varchar field in one of the tables with characters, but one of the tables (or multiple) have that field as a numeric data type.

Comment: Mike, I just queried the information schema, all the columns in question are `DATA_TYPE = TEXT`, however the fields `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` can vary. Some are `256`, some are `1024`, and some are `16777216`. Do you think this could be influencing this error?

Comment: The error explicitly states that it thinks the values should be numeric for some reason, so it's not the length of the fields.  You might want to open a support ticket with Snowflake.  Include the query_id with the error and see if they can help track it down for you.  These things are nearly always something small and obvious once you find them, but it's hard to guess through stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks very much Mike, I'll do just that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the error message that you get is not related to this column, but with another column where you might be casting the data as NUMERIC, but instead getting this value 'Exchange Gain Or Loss'.

One way to ignore this conversion error, is to use TRY_CAST instead of CAST, so when a value can not be converted to the intended data type, it will simply return NULL